# How to place Vaadin confirmdialog ok and cancel button in center

Tags: vaadin

I have been using the [`ConfirmDialog`](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/confirmdialog) [add-on](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/addons.html) from the [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) [Directory](https://vaadin.com/directory).

Is it possible to put the *OK* and *Cancel* buttons in the center of the window? By default it is in the right corner of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a layout with buttons in the middle and set it as the content of ConfirmDialog. You can get the buttons using ConfirmDialog.get...Button(). Example:

```
    ConfirmDialog cd = ConfirmDialog.getFactory().create("Title", "", "OK",
            "Cancel");
    cd.setHeight("400px");
    cd.setWidth("400px");
    HorizontalLayout buttons = new HorizontalLayout();
    buttons.addComponent(cd.getCancelButton());
    buttons.addComponent(cd.getOkButton());
    VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout(buttons);
    content.setComponentAlignment(buttons, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    content.setSizeFull();
    cd.setContent(content);
    cd.show(this, null, false);
```

However I agree with Jan that the good practice is having them in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the buttons in the right lower corner is good practice when it comes to usability. Have a look at http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-ok-buttons-in-dialog-boxes-work-best-on-the-right/ for more details. I would advice not to sacrifice behavior conventions for personal taste.