# Vaadin ConfirmDialog changing the title

Tags: localization, dialog, vaadin

I want to change the title "Confirm" of a ConfirmDialog to something in my language. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583002/how-to-place-vaadin-confirmdialog-ok-and-cancel-button-in-center), but the code does not make sense to me since the show method in my vaadin addon is a static method and it appears to be impossible to show a dialog returned by the factory.

I used this code to wrap the dialog:

```
package com.xxx.dialog;

import org.vaadin.dialogs.ConfirmDialog;

import com.xxx.message.MessageByLocaleService;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;

public class DeleteDialog {
    private ConfirmDialog cd;

    public DeleteDialog(MessageByLocaleService messageByLocaleService) {
        cd = ConfirmDialog.getFactory()
                .create(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("caption.confirm"),
                "", "OK",  "Cancel", "");
    }

    public abstract static class MyListener {
        public abstract void receive();
    }

    public void show(UI ui, MessageByLocaleService messageByLocaleService, MyListener yes, MyListener cancel) {
        //this.setCaption(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("caption.confirm"));
        //this.setMessageLabel(new Label(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("caption.confirm")));
        cd.show(ui, messageByLocaleService.getMessage("confirm.delete"),
                new ConfirmDialog.Listener() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    public void onClose(ConfirmDialog dialog) {
                        if (dialog.isConfirmed()) {
                            // Confirmed to continue
                            yes.receive();
                        } else {
                            // User did not confirm
                            cancel.receive();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
}
```

I had this `class DeleteDialog` as `extends ConfirmDialog` for some time, that is why some of the attempts I made that are commented out don't make sense.

Comment: Have you check if `messageByLocaleService.getMessage("caption.confirm")` was returning null?

Comment: It should not be null, the translation is in the translations file. The problem is that `show` is a static method, where i need a class method. Maybe I'll downgrade the addon version to one that has a non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve my goal by setting a new default factory.

```
package com.xxx.dialog;

import org.vaadin.dialogs.ConfirmDialog;

import com.xxx.message.MessageByLocaleService;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;

public class DeleteDialog {
    ConfirmDialog.Factory oldFactory;
    ConfirmDialog.Factory factory;

    public DeleteDialog(MessageByLocaleService messageByLocaleService) {
        oldFactory = ConfirmDialog.getFactory();
        factory = new ConfirmDialog.Factory() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public ConfirmDialog create(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, String arg4) {
            ConfirmDialog cd = oldFactory.create(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("caption.confirm"),
                    "", messageByLocaleService.getMessage("message.ok"),
                      messageByLocaleService.getMessage("message.cancel"), null);
            cd.setMessage(messageByLocaleService.getMessage("confirm.delete"));
            return cd;
            }
        };
    }

    public abstract static class MyListener {
        public abstract void receive();
    }

    public void show(UI ui, MessageByLocaleService messageByLocaleService, MyListener yes, MyListener cancel) {

        ConfirmDialog.setFactory(factory);
        ConfirmDialog.show(ui, messageByLocaleService.getMessage("confirm.delete"),
                new ConfirmDialog.Listener() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    public void onClose(ConfirmDialog dialog) {
                        if (dialog.isConfirmed()) {
                            // Confirmed to continue
                            yes.receive();
                        } else {
                            // User did not confirm
                            cancel.receive();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
}
```